# having audio play on click

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onclick

I am trying to get some buttons to work with sound to no success. For the page I am using I have it set up as such:

```js
// javascript file for gun tutorial//
window.onload=function()
{
 var extraAmmo = 210;
 var maxAmmo = 30;
 var currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
 
 var extraAmmoHud = document.getElementById("extra-ammo");
 var currentAmmoHud = document.getElementById("current-ammo");
 
 var shootButton = document.getElementById("shoot-button");
 var unloadButton = document.getElementById("unload-button");
 var reloadButton = document.getElementById("reload-button");
  refreshScreen();
  
 shootButton.onclick=function()
 {
  if(currentAmmo > 0)
  {
   currentAmmo--;
   refreshScreen();
  }
 }
 unloadButton.onclick=function() 
 {
     if (currentAmmo > 0)
  {
            unloadTimer = setTimeout(unloadButton.onclick, 150)
         currentAmmo--;
         refreshScreen();
     } 
  else unloadTimer = null;
 }
 reloadButton.onclick=function()
 {
  var difference = getDifference();
  if(extraAmmo >= difference)
  {
   currentAmmo += difference;
   extraAmmo -= difference;
  }
  else
  {
   currentAmmo += extraAmmo;
   extraAmmo -= extraAmmo;
  }
  refreshScreen();
  
  function getDifference()
  {
   return maxAmmo -currentAmmo;
  }
 }
 function refreshScreen()
 {
  extraAmmoHud.innerHTML="Extra Ammo: " + extraAmmo;
  currentAmmoHud.innerHTML="Current Ammo: " + currentAmmo;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Gun Tutorial</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<script src="js/gun.js"></script>
<audio src="sounds/GunShot.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="sounds/GunShotFullAuto.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="sounds/GunCockingFast.wav"></audio>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
 <header id="header">
  <h1>Welcome to the Gun Show</h1>
 </header>
 <div id="content"></div>
 <form>
 <div id="boxobuttons">
  <input type="button" value="Shoot" id="shoot-button" />
  <input type="button" value="Unload" id="unload-button" />
  <input type="button" value="Reload" id="reload-button" />
 </div>
 
  <div id="ammo-count">
   <p id="current-ammo"></p>
   <p id="extra-ammo"></p>
  </div>
 </form>
 <footer>
 </footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to see if I need to have the sound act as a variable, and each individual variable can then be inserted into  the different variables (shootButton, unloadButton, and reloadButton), or would I have to do something completely seperate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you load your sounds just in javascript?

For example: `var gunshot = new Audio('GunShot.mp3');`

And if you then have your sounds, you can just place them between your code like this:

```
shootButton.onclick=function()
    {
        if(currentAmmo > 0)
        {
            currentAmmo--;
            gunshot.play();
            refreshScreen();
        }
    }
```

I hope I answered your question with this.

Comment: Thanks for the input Thomas, give me a moment, and I will get back with you and tell you if it works.

Comment: It looks, like a no, for the moment, I want to say I identified the problem, being that, maybe it doesn't like the audio files being in it's own folder (sounds) so I am going to move them into the open with the index.html to see if that works.

Comment: moving it to the open with index.html worked, now to do the same for unload and reload

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me from this code how you're trying to play your audio files. The audio tag is primarily designed for embedding user controlled media.

If you're doing behind the scenes manipulation with short audio files, I'd recommend working with the Web Audio API directly, ideally serving your audio with a [bufferLoader](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/js/buffer-loader.js) object. The first half of this article covers everything you'd need to know:

[Getting Started with Web Audio API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/)

Comment: Uh...sure, if you don't care about W3C standards or supporting all browsers, and you love complexity. `<audio>` is a thousand times less compex for basic audio.